# VB Script press enter instead of click button

Tags: vbscript, return, enter

I have a script that has a single text box and a single button to continue. Right now you have to click the button or press <kbd>tab</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd>. How can I send <kbd>enter</kbd> from the text box to continue? Thanks.

Also, a side question that may not have an answer. This is saved as an `.hta` and runs before a Windows Sysprep process. If it runs on a laptop, and the lid is closed when it starts, the screen is completely blank. I can press <kbd>tab</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to make it continue, as if I was seeing it, and then when it restarts its fine again. Any idea on why its blank and how to make it show always would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sysprep Deployment</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION 
     ID="objCompDeploy" 
     APPLICATIONNAME="Sysprep Deployment"
     SCROLL="no"
     SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
     maximizeButton="no"
     minimizeButton="no"
     sysMenu="yes"
>
</head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">

Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Sub Window_onLoad
window.resizeTo 400,200
ComputerNameArea.Focus
  CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys "^{Home}"

'turn off setup flag in registry so we can query wmi
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\SystemSetupInProgress", 0, "REG_DWORD"

'query wmi for serial number
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20
strComputer = "."
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
   Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_BIOS", "WQL", _
                                          wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

   For Each objItem In colItems
      serialNumber = objItem.SerialNumber
   Next

'turn setup flag back on
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\SystemSetupInProgress", 1, "REG_DWORD"

'put the serial number that was retrieved in the textbox
ComputerNameArea.Value = serialNumber

End Sub 

Sub modUnattend

run_button.Disabled = True

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

base = Wshshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemRoot%")
unattendFile = base & "\Panther\unattend.xml"

   computerName = ComputerNameArea.Value

 Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
 xmlDoc.load unattendFile

 'Iterate through Unattend.xml searching for nodes and properties to replace
 Set oNodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectNodes("/unattend/settings/component/ComputerName")
 For each n in oNodes
  n.text = computerName
  xmlDoc.save unattendFile
 Next


'launch the continuation of setup in a hidden window and wait for return
'if we dont wait, closing mshta, closes windeploy.exe
WshShell.Run "%WINDIR%\System32\oobe\windeploy.exe", 0, True
idTimer = window.setTimeout("closeHTA", 5000, "VBScript")
End Sub

Sub closeHTA
window.close
End Sub

Sub commandLine
WshShell.Run "%WINDIR%\System32\cmd.exe", 1, True
End Sub

</SCRIPT>
<body>
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>Computer Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="ComputerNameArea" size="30" maxlength="15" value="computer"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tab then Enter to Continue</td>
</tr>
</table> 
<p align="right">
<input id=runbutton  class="button" type="button" value="Continue" name="run_button" onClick="modUnattend">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with type **Submit** instead of **button** !

```
<input id=runbutton  class="button" type="Submit" value="Continue" name="run_button" onClick="modUnattend">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, I added a EventListener to the enter key and and made it fire the click event when the enter key is pressed

```
<input id=runbutton  class="button" type="button" value="Continue" name="run_button" onKeyDown="if (event.keyCode == 13){ this.click }" onClick="modUnattend">
```